# What should I do with my 2 Domains

Tags: seo, google, domains, multiple-domains

I have a main domain

```
www.example.com
```

We currently are in the process of changing domains to

```
www.example2.com
```

but I really want to keep the existing domain working.

I have set up the webserver to serve the same site for either address and all links are relative. So if you go to `example.com` and click on a link you go to `example.com/courses` or if you go to `example2.com` and click you go to `example2.com/courses`.

This works fine and I am happy with it, however someone said to me that Google doesn't like this and thinks I am doing dodgy SEO stuff (which I'm not).

Does Google mind if I do this?

Is there a way that I can tell Google these two domains are the same content while not having to redirect one to the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you point two domains to the same website/content this is duplicate content and exactly what Google does *not* want. They want one authoritative URL for all content to display in their search results.

If you want two domains to display the same content you need to decide which one is the one you want in Google's search results and make that the canonical domain. All of the page in the other domain then need to use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to let Google know the *other* domain's page is the canonical URL for that page and should be shown in the search results.

Comment: will the canonical <link ref be relevant if the domains rather than the rest of the url are different?

Comment: Canonical URLs can do cross-domain